# Observer pattern for unpredictable observation time

Tags: observer-pattern

I have a situation where objects are created at unpredictable times. Some of these objects are created before an important event, some after. If the event already happened, I make the object execute stuff right away. If the event is forthcoming, I make the object observe the event. When the event triggers, the object is notified and executes the same code.

```
if (subject.eventAlreadyHappened()) {
    observer.executeStuff();
} else {
    subject.subscribe(observer);
}
```

Is there another design pattern to wrap or even replace this observer pattern? I think it looks a little dirty to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative would be as follows.

Observers are notified of the event through the method

```
// Method on all observers.
void notify(Event event)
```

All new objects are subscribed to the notification, so the subject, instead
of

```
if (subject.eventAlreadyHappened()) {
    observer.executeStuff();
} else {
    subject.subscribe(observer);
}
```

does simply

```
subject.subscribe(observer);
```

When the event occurs, the subscribed observer are notified, and the event is cached:

```
// Method on subject.
void handleEvent(Event event)
{
    // lastEvent is a member variable of subject.
    lastEvent = event;
    ...
    for (Observer observer : subscribedObservers())
    {
        observer.notify(event);
    }
}
```

When a new object is subscribed, it is notified immediately if the event
has occurred already:

```
// Method on subject.
void subscribe(Observer observer)
{
    // Add observer to list.

    ...

    if (lastEvent != null)
    {
        observer.notify(lastEvent);
    }
}
```

Finally, the observer has a method notify:

```
// Method on observer.
void notify(Event event)
{
    executeStuff();
}
```

So basically the difference is that the subject immediately sends
a notification to a newly subscribed object if at the moment of subscription
the event has already occurred.

I hope this helps.

Comment: For the standard observer pattern, do programmers expect this behavior upon subscription? If not, then should I create two subscription functions - one just like your example, and another to only publish future events?

Comment: Do you mean that with the standard observer pattern you only want to be notified about events that have occurred after subscription?

Comment: I don't know what the standard is. Is the standard to be notified of future events only or is it standard to be notified when someone subscribes late?

Comment: I honestly do not know if there is such a standard. But I do not think there is anything wrong for an object to generate an event when another object subscribes.